# <a href> automatic link without click

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, href, innerhtml

I have this:

```
document.getElementById('printableArea').innerHTML = "<a href='javascript:changePage(\"" + catagor + "\")' onClick='javascript:changePage(\"" + catagor + "\")'> CLICK HERE</a>";
```

For example, catagor = worldru.
So I'll have: "CLICK ME" and a link: javascript:changePage("worldru")

I want to go straight to the function with this parameter ( " catagor " ), but I don't know how to write it with the " " ?

```
changePage(\"" + catagor + "\");
```

It's not working, what is my mistake?
The second way I'm looking for is how to make the  automatic, without waiting for the user to click on it?

Thanks

Comment: can you please set up a jfiddle example? it would be more simple to help you.

Comment: And by `changePage`, do you actually have a function with that name or you want to redirect the browser to another page?

Answer (score 0):

Anything inside the `onclick` event is already interpreted as javascript, no need to specify it.

```
document.getElementById('printableArea').innerHTML = "<a href='javascript:void(0);' onClick='changePage(\"" + catagor + "\")'> CLICK HERE</a>";
```

Use `void(0)` in the `href` attribute to prevent the browser from trying to open the link.
The `onclick` event will be triggered as it should.

I enclosed the `catagor` var in double quotes, which is inside the `onclick` event's single quotes.
Just make sure that your var is accessible in this scope.

Also, I have no idea what you mean with "automatic", you can obviously set a timer in miliseconds with `setTimeout()` or put in the `body`'s `onload`:

```
window.location=catagor; //the "window" reference is usually unnecessary
```

**edit:**

Add this to your function:

```
changePage(catagor);
```

This will call the `changePage` function passing the parameter as you asked in the comments.

Here's the modified link example: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/zscpC/1/)

Comment: this is a function in another file .

Comment: its not working ..
i want this <a href> with the javascript function that i wrote , but without the CLICK ME .. to go automatic to the javascript function, without clicking.  can i do this ?

Comment: Yes, but what do you mean "Automatic"? As soon as the page loads?

Comment: when i go to this function .. all this <a href> is inside a function-

function change_tem(catagor){
 document.getElementById('printableArea').innerHTML = "<a href='javascript:changePage(\"" + catagor + "\")' onClick='javascript:changePage(\"" + catagor + "\")'> CLICK ME</a>";
 }

Comment: Alright, try out my last edit. That's how you'd call the function passing the parameter, just add it where you want to call the function. F5 the page if it's not showing (my SO page is slightly glitchy).

Comment: i need to pass this : "catagor" , this is my problem ..
the link sholud be like this :  javascript:changePage("worldru") 
when catagor =worldru .. i need to add the "" , how i do that?

Comment: Do you want to call the function automatically or change the link? Well, both of these are in my answer. :) `onClick='changePage(\"" + catagor + "\")'>`, this works, I'm escaping the `"` which is enclosing the whole `innerHTML` method's value. Just make sure your `catagor` var is accessible in the scope (e.g. being a global var).

Comment: I made a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/zscpC/1/) with the modified link, check if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: thanks .. but i still need to click on "click me " , i need to automatically go to the link and call the function

Comment: I'm not 100% sure on what you mean with `automatically go to the link and call the function`.. You mean, scrolling the browser to the link? Or do you mean calling the `changePage` function as soon as the link is displayed? If it's the latter, just add `changePage(catagor);` inside your `change_tem` function.

Comment: i need to add the Quotation mark to the variable ,its need to be like this : javascript:changePage("worldru") 
ill call it in my php file -
echo "<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='javascript'>changePage('$catagor');</SCRIPT>";

now how i add to my variable - $catagor - the Quotation mark?
i need to pass to the function "$catagor" and not just $catagor

Comment: You didn't even tag your question with php -_-, but ok, you're printing the javascript through php? Then I assume `$catagor` is a fixed value printed from the php, then from your example, `changePage('$catagor');` is the right way to do that. What problem are you having atm?

Comment: i need to pass with  Quotation marks , in your way its will be 
 javascript:changePage(worldru),
and i need 
 javascript:changePage("worldru")

Comment: Yes, I assumed it was inside a javascript file grabbing the `catagor` var from your javascript, where you'd use `changePage(catagor)`, seeing as `catagor` would be already a string `var`. Now if you're printing it from the PHP, your example above `changePage('$catagor');` is enclosing the php `$catagor` var in single quotes which identify it as a string. What's the problem again? Is it in the link or function call or..?